# CakePHP 1.3 how to render views before displaying content

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 1.3. I want to get all html content (table,div..) of my page (.ctp) with CSS to concatinate with other file pdf,

I tried to use something like:

```
$view = new View(null, false);
$view->set('timecard','masque');
$view->viewPath = 'pdf'; 
$output = $view->render('pdf', 'pdf');
```

OR

```
$view = new View($this, false);
$view->set(compact('timecard', 'masque'));
$html = $view->render('view_name');
```

thank's for helping ..

Answer (score 0):

Please test this code:

```
/* Make sure the controller doesn't auto render. */
$this->autoRender = false;

/* Set up new view that won't enter the ClassRegistry */
$view = new View($this, false);
$view->set('text', 'Hello World');
$view->viewPath = 'elements';

/* Grab output into variable without the view actually outputting! */
$view_output = $view->render('box');
```